# Excel user getting conversion error from SQL Server when refreshing data from view

Tags: sql-server, excel, type-conversion, database-connection, export-to-excel

**(EDITED - data type and language info added)**

I created a view `Foo2` for an employee. Whenever he tries to refresh the data, he is getting error:

> [DataSource.Error] Microsoft SQL Server: the conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

When I (sysadmin role) try to refresh data in the Excel sheet everything goes smoothly and query in SSMS does not throw any errors. The user also uses another view `Foo1` - a previous version of `Foo2`. That one works as expected.

Right now I am at this point:

- I changed the `SELECT` statements in `Foo1` and `Foo2` to be exactly the same
- The views are in the same database and schema
- The employee is accessing the server and database by being a member of a windows login group
- View properties windows are the same except for two extended properties in the `Foo1` view - MS_DiagramPane1 and MS_DiagramPaneCount (don't know what they are)

Language and data type related info:

- Collation of the views is the same (`SQL_Slovak_CP1250_CI_AS`)
- Language of both `LOGIN`s is the same (`Slovak - slovenčina`)
- Collation of both `USER`s is the same (`SQL_Slovak_CP1250_CI_AS`)
- We both have Slovak version of MS 365
- No `CAST`, `CONVERT` or other data type changes occour in the view
- Data types in both `Foo1` and `Foo2` are the same

I suspect, that the user group was given a permission on that particular view `Foo1`, but I don't know how to test this theory.

- SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.2000.5)
- Excel version: Microsoft 365 for Enterprise

Comment: Do the different `LOGIN`s have different language settings, by any chance?

Comment: Side Note: Why are still running the RTM version of SQL Server 2019? The initial release has had multiple bug fixes (which were quite prevalent in the initial release) and several security fixes you are not patches against. What do you have against applying updates for the last 2 years?

Comment: Clearly there is a mismatch in the settings, probably the `language` or `dateformat`. The temporary solution is to use a fixed `style` for the conversion (don't know which because you haven't given us the data). I'd strongly suggest you investigate why you are converting values in the first place, you should always store data in the correct data type.

Comment: Both `LOGIN`s and `USER`s have the same language settings

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the mismatch in `language` and `dateformat`? All of the datetime columns are stored as the same data type same - `smalldatetime`.

Comment: Amongst other things setting the language also affects the default date/datetime formats used for `cast`. e.g.: `set language N'British'` will use `dmy`; `set language N'us_english'` will use `mdy` and `set language N'hrvatski'` will use `ymd`. Since different logins can have different default languages specified they can get different outcomes from `cast`.

Comment: Your error message occurs when attempting to convert a varchar value to a smalldatetime so you should be looking for instances of `cast(someColumnName as smalldatetime)` in your view/s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the `WHERE` part of he `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT
    clmn1
    ,clmn2
    ,clmn3
FROM table1
WHERE clmn1 > '2017-12-31'
```

The column `clmn1` is data type `smalldatetime`. I still don't understand the reason, since implicit conversion from `varchar` to `smalldatetime` should be possible. At least according to the chart here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

The `SELECT` statement works as dasired after using `CONVERT` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    clmn1
    ,clmn2
    ,clmn3
FROM table1
WHERE clmn1 > CONVERT(smalldatetime, '2017-12-31 23:59:59', 120)
```

I guess I'm missing something. Anyway - problem solved.